# How to prove that $\cos\theta$ is even without using unit circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-writing

The proofs I have come across on showing that $\cos \theta$ is even is something like this:

> 1. In a unit circle, $\cos\theta$ gives you the $x$ coordinate after traveling $\theta$ radians counterclockwise.
> 2. Since, moving $\theta$ radians counterclockwise and $\theta$ radians clockwise i.e $-\theta$ will give you the same x coordinate, we have:
>
>    $\cos(\theta)=\cos (-\theta)$

It is possible to prove this without relying on any diagrams/geometry? For example, to prove that $f(x)=x^2$ is even we do the following:

> $f(-x)=(-x)^2=x^2=f(x)$

Can we do something similar for proving $\cos \theta$ too? If not, why?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be satisfactory but you can always just use the power-series definition for the cosine.

Comment: Somehow, you ought to appeal to the definition of $\cos$, but that definition is geometrical. Of course, you could always decide to adopt another definition. For instance through the Taylor series, I'v seen that in some analysis books. But it's kind of artificial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you allow

$e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta, \tag{1}$

then you can simply observe that

$e^{i(-\theta)} = \cos (- \theta) + i \sin(-\theta), \tag{2}$

and that

$e^{i(-\theta)} = (e^{i \theta})^{-1}, \tag{3}$

and recall that for unimodular complex numbers $z$ we have $z^{-1} = z^*$ to conclude that

$e^{i (-\theta)} = (e^{i \theta})^*, \tag{4}$

whence

$\cos (-\theta) + i \sin (-\theta) = \cos \theta - i\sin \theta, \tag{5}$

from which we infer that

$\cos (-\theta) = \cos \theta, \tag{6}$

I.e., $\cos$ is even.  You also get $\sin$ is odd thrown in for free.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do without diagrams and geometry, incl. arc length, you have to use an *analytic definition* of cosine. The simplest way is via the function $t\mapsto e^{it}$ (see Robert Lewis' answer). Another way is studying the coupled ODE system
$$c'(t)=-s(t), \quad s'(t)=c(t); \quad c(0)=1,\ s(0)=0\ .$$
According to the existence and uniqueness theorem for such systems it has a unique solution valid in some neighborhood $|t|<h$ of the origin, and it is then easy to see that the function $c(\cdot)=:\cos$ is even. But  a lot of work is needed  to prove that this solution can be extended to all of ${\mathbb R}$ and that it is periodic with some positive fundamental period, denoted by $2\pi$. (The latter problem you also have with the function $t\mapsto e^{it}$.)