# General trignometry doubt

Tags: trigonometry

We know $\cos(-x) = \cos x$

Now my doubt is that the condition is true only when $x\in [0,\pi]$
as in fourth quadrant cosine is positive .

Or it belongs to every real number .

Comment: this is true in general

Comment: $\cos$ is $2\pi$ periodic and you have the statement on $[-\pi,\pi]$ whose length is $1$ period, so...

Comment: Yes, this is true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. $\cos(x)$ is an even function:
$$f(-x)=f(x)$$
See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510877/how-to-prove-that-cos-theta-is-even-without-using-unit-circle) for a proof.

Comment: I think you are confused between positive values and equal values, cos(120) = cos(-120), here values are equal but the value is negative i.e -0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cosine is positive in the 1st and 4th quadrants and negative in 2nd and 3rd.

If $x$ lies in 1st quadrant $-x$ will lie in 4th.

If $x$ lies in 2nd quadrant $-x$ will lie in 3rd.

If $x$ lies in 3rd quadrant $-x$ will lie in 2nd.

If $x$ lies in 4th quadrant $-x$ will lie in 3rd.

Thus the sign of cosine will be same for $x$ lying in any quadrant or in other words, $cos(x)=cos(-x)$ for any real number $x$.

Answer (score 7):

We can think about this geometrically!

Let $x_{\theta}$ denote a unit vector that makes the angle $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis. The function $\cos(\theta)$ is the answer to the question

> *"What is the horizontal length of $x_{\theta}$?"*

Now, consider the vector $x_{-\theta}$. This is just the reflection of of $x_{\theta}$ across the $x$-axis. So the answer to the question *"What is the horizontal length of $x_{-\theta}$?"* is the same! This is exactly the value of $\cos(\theta)$, so therefore

$$\cos(-\theta) = \cos(\theta)$$

As for your question about values $x\in[0,\pi]$, this is simply asking questions about vectors in the upper-half plane. Since a reflection across the $x$-axis leaves this plane when $x\in(0,\pi)$, talking about $-\theta$ doesn't make sense in that context.

Using this intuition about $\cos(\theta)$, what can you say about $\sin(-\theta)$?

Answer (score 3):

Case 1:

$x \in [0,\pi]$.  Then $cos(x) = \cos(-x)$.  You seem to accept that.

Case 2:

$x \in [-\pi, 0]$.  Then $-x \in [0,\pi]$.  So $\cos(x) = \cos(-(-x)) = \cos(-x)$.

Case 3:

$x \in \mathbb R$.  Then there is some $k \in \mathbb Z$ so the $x = k(2\pi) + x'; -\pi < x' \le \pi$.  So $\cos (x) = \cos(x' + 2k\pi) = \cos(x') = \cos(-x') = \cos(-x - 2k\pi) = \cos (-x)$.

(Because $trig(x + 2k\pi) = trig(x)$ for all integers $k$ and any trig function.  [Because circles have circumference of $2\pi$.])

Answer (score 2):

You have the [prosthaphaeresis formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)
$$ \cos{A}-\cos{B} = -2\sin{\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)}, $$
(subtract two instances of the addition formula for $\cos$) and putting $B=-A$, the first sine is $\sin{0}=0$, so $\cos{A}-\cos{(-A)}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is in the fourth quadrant, $-x$ is in the first quadrant. As both cosines are positive, there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the sign of $x$ with the sign of cosine. That is, sometimes $\cos(-x)$ is positive (because $x<\frac{\pi}{2}$).

As the comments point out, $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$ for all $x$. To understand this intuitively, imagine the unit circle. Recall how the $x$-value of any coordinate on the unit circle is equal to cosine. Now randomly choose an angle $x$ on the unit circle. Note that the angle $-x$ is the reflection of $x$ across the $y$-axis, which means these two points have the same $x$-coordinates. Therefore, $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$.